# avconv - Filter drawtext doesn't work

Tags: avconv

I' going to add some text to a video segment using `-vf` but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried

```
avconv -ss 00:00:20 -i input.mp4 -t 00:00:10 -vcodec copy -acodec copy \
  -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='hello world':x=0:y=0:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" output.mp4
```

But the text doesn't show up. I know that `-t` argument should appear after `-i` or the duration won't be set. I wonder if I misplace `-vf` in this case. Would anyone tell me how to make it?

P.S. I install it with `apt-get install ffmpeg`. Software info:

```
avconv version 0.8.9-6:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.13.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  9 2013 19:09:48 with gcc 4.7.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case we want to add text to our video using the `drawtext` filter we can not make use of the `copy` video codec.

Adding text to a video will change the video data. Therefore we have to re-encode the video stream using any codec other than `copy`.

Comment: If I remove `-vcodec` avconv will report an error "encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results. Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it." Is it any mistakes I made during installation?

Comment: Your source may be aac encoded... you can choose any vcodec or acodec supported for re-encoding, or use the `-target` option for some defaults. See http://libav.org/avconv.html#Codec-AVOptions

Comment: In fact I didn't have `libavcodec-extra-53` installed. After an `apt-get` it is now all right.

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='hello world':x=0:y=0:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" output.mp4
```

tested on this mp4 sample [file](http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip).